# data.table : unexpected error with non-standard evaluation

Tags: r, data.table

I have 2 cases to share :

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = 1:5, y = rep(100, 5))
dt1 <- data.table(col_name = 1:5, y = rep(100, 5))
dt
#   x   y
#1: 1 100
#2: 2 100
#3: 3 100
#4: 4 100
#5: 5 100

dt1
#   col_name   y
#1:        1 100
#2:        2 100
#3:        3 100
#4:        4 100
#5:        5 100


func <- function(data, col_name){
  data[,':='(cum_wt = cumsum(eval(as.name(col_name))))][] # calc the cumulative sum
  return(data)
}

# Case 1 : when the column name is different than function argument
func(dt, "x")
#   x   y cum_wt
#1: 1 100      1
#2: 2 100      3
#3: 3 100      6
#4: 4 100     10
#5: 5 100     15

# Case 2 : when the column name is same as function argument
func(dt1, "col_name")
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) :object '1' not found

Could someone help me understand the cause? and how to make this function work for both cases ?

I know of workaround for these : like

```
data$cum_wt <- cumsum(data[[col_name]])
```

But I wanted to LEARN the reason for that error . Thanks

Comment: I usually use `get` (or `mget`) in such situations - have you tried it?

Comment: @docendodiscimus no I haven't.. i can try that.. do you know the reason for this behaviour though?

Comment: I don't know the reason (my guess is that it has to do with environments, but could be something else too)

Comment: It searches for col_name in the table's environment first, and `as.name(1:5)` evaluates to `\`1\``, so I guess the lesson is: define the expression to be evaluated outside of `DT[...]`.

Comment: @docendodiscimus `get(col_name)` does fail as well.

Answer (score 2):

You may try the alternative implementation. It uses `.SD` and passes the column name as character to the `.Sdcols` parameter. (Perhaps, not the fastest approach but it's returning the desired output.)

```
func2 <- function(dat, col_name) {
  checkmate::assert_data_table(dat)
  checkmate::assert_string(col_name)
  checkmate::assert_choice(col_name, names(dat))
  dat[, cum_wt := lapply(.SD, cumsum), .SDcols = col_name] # calc the cumulative sum
  return(dat[])
}
```

Note that I've renamed `data` to `dat` because `data` is the name of an R function.

```
func2(dt, "x")
#   x   y cum_wt
#1: 1 100      1
#2: 2 100      3
#3: 3 100      6
#4: 4 100     10
#5: 5 100     15

func2(dt, "y")
#   x   y cum_wt
#1: 1 100    100
#2: 2 100    200
#3: 3 100    300
#4: 4 100    400
#5: 5 100    500

func2(dt1, "col_name")
#   col_name   y cum_wt
#1:        1 100      1
#2:        2 100      3
#3:        3 100      6
#4:        4 100     10
#5:        5 100     15
```

---

The OP requested an explanation of the error. So, I tried to run the OP's original function with `verbose = TRUE`:

```
func <- function(data, col_name){
  data[,':='(cum_wt = cumsum(eval(as.name(col_name)))), verbose = TRUE][] # calc the cumulative sum
  return(data)
}

func(dt1, "col_name")
```

> '(m)get' found in j. ansvars being set to all columns. Use .SDcols or a single j=eval(macro) instead. Both will detect the columns used which is important for efficiency.
>       Old: col_name,y,cum_wt
>       New: col_name,y,cum_wt
>        Error in get(col_name) : invalid first argument

Unfortunately, this gave no better insight what the root cause of the error is but it shows that `data.table` suggests a second method besides using `.SDcols`:

```
func3 <- function(data, col_name){
  j_expr <- paste0(":=(cum_wt = cumsum(", col_name, ")")
  data[, j = eval(j_expr), verbose = TRUE][]
  return(data)
}
func3(dt1, "col_name")
#Detected that j uses these columns: <none> 
#   col_name   y cum_wt
#1:        1 100      1
#2:        2 100      3
#3:        3 100      6
#4:        4 100     10
#5:        5 100     15
```

So, I think [Frank's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343269/data-table-unexpected-error-with-non-standard-evaluation/43344183#comment73756793_43343269)
*It searches for `col_name` in the table's environment first, and `as.name(1:5)` evaluates to `` `1` ``,*...
is the only explanation.

Comment: I had this also... i just was too lazy to mention all the list of workarounds i had ...thank you for mentioning this.. could you help me understand the cause of my error though?

Answer (score 0):

Change the second function parameter e.g.

```
func <- function(data, col){
   data[,':='(cum_wt = cumsum(eval(as.name(col))))][] # calc the cumulative sum
  return(data)
}
```

Comment: my dear friend that's not an answer !

Comment: This fails if applied to a data.table with a `col` column, e.g., with `dt2 <- data.table(col = 1:5, y = rep(100, 5))`, `func(dt2, "col")` produces the same error as the OP reported.